# How do you tell sbt-eclipse to ignore (errors of) a very specific folder under /src

Tags: eclipse, sbteclipse

I have an infrastructure project that contains other projects as *resources*. (Because it compiles them on the fly). One of those contained projects is deliberately one that fails to compile.

This makes the entire project show in eclipse as "with errors".
How can I make sbt-eclipse configure eclipse such that e.g. anything under `src/main/resources/foo` should be ignored?

- Of course this isn't exactly the scenario eclipse was built for, but might there be some clean way around it? as much as it matters, sbt itself does not try to compile these resources.
- If not, maybe a way to tell eclipse to not even load source
  directories under `src/main/resources`?

Thanks!

[image]